# Network setup using CNI

Tags: kubernetes

As I check that weave or flannel or calico network link has been removed from http://kubernetes.io page while we are creating cluster  using kubeadm way. Now as per CKA exam we are not allowed to open any 3rd party link. Any one having idea how to setup calico or flannel network in the CKA exam or if any page can contain that setup in kubernetes.io ?

Answer (score 1):

You can still go back to an older version of the doc [here](https://v1-17.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/) which has instructions on how to install CNI Plugins such as calico or weave.

At top right corner you can select an older version such as 1.17.

Having said that if sometime is not part of `kubernetes.io` it will not come in exam.